# How to assemble a link to a specific view in django admin?

Tags: django

Inside my subclass of `admin.ModelAdmin`, I want to manually assemble a url to a different edit view for a different model.

What I currently have is:

- app
- model
- id (PK of the model)

The question now is how I can obtain the prefix of the server.
e.g. I access the admin via url http://myserver.com/admin/app/model/
How can I retrieve http://myserver.com/admin in a server agnostic way inside my `ModelAdmin` subclass ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `reverse` function, as documented in [reversing admin urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls).

For example:

```
urlresolvers.reverse('admin:appname_modelname_change', args=(id,))
```